# How to change header within WordPress for each page NOT header image

Tags: php, wordpress-theming

What I would like to do is have a different header (not header image) appear on each page of my WordPress website, for example on the about page I'd like the header to be blue with text and on the home page i'd like the header to be red with text. I have search google for answers but the posts that come up are very older and show methods on how to replace the header image on each page within wordpress.

Would I do something like the below script and place it in function.php? (I'm newbie to WordPress)

```
<?php if ( is_about_page() ) {
if ( function_exists( 'about-header.php' ) ) { 

}
} ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could probably use the function `get_header()` (https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_header) in combination with the page name ($pagename global WP variable), by doing something like this:
Apart from using the main - default header in `header.php`, create your custom header PHP files following the name convention `header-{name}.php`, in which you put your header specific code.
Then, in `page.php` you can do:

```
get_header($pagename);
```

This will probably call the appropriate header based on your page name.